# I'm setting up a map with Here maps api and I am having trouble removing a map listener

Tags: javascript, here-api

I want to add several markers to a map and then have the user click on the map and display a different marker for the clicked location.

I don't seem to be able to remove the `event listener` before displaying the new marker so that further map clicks are disabled.

I get Uncaught TypeError:

> Cannot read property '__closure_events_fn_249633963' of undefined
>   sample code I've tried.

```
        function setUpClickListener(map) {
    // Attach an event listener to map
    map.addEventListener('tap', function(evt) {addMarker(evt);});
    // map.addEventListener('tap', function addMarker(evt));
    // map.addEventListener('tap', addMarker(function (evt)));
    // map.addEventListener('tap', addMarker(evt));
    }
    function addMarker(myevt) {
    // remove event listener so no further map clicks can be made
    map.removeEventListener();
    // add clicked marker
    var coord = map.screenToGeo(myevt.currentPointer.viewportX, myevt.currentPointer.viewportY);
    var sLat = coord.lat;
    var sLng = coord.lng;
    var svgMarkup = '<svg width="24" height="24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">' +
    '<rect stroke="white" fill="#ff0000" x="1" y="1" width="22" height="22" />' +
    '<text x="12" y="18" font-size="12pt" font-family="Arial" font-weight="bold" ' +
    'text-anchor="middle" fill="white">S</text></svg>';
    //add marker
    var myIcon = new H.map.Icon(svgMarkup),
        coords = {lat:sLat, lng:sLng},
        marker = new H.map.Marker(coords, {icon: myIcon});
    // Add the marker to the map
    map.addObject(marker);
    }
```

Can anyone give me the correct syntax to remove the listener?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Explanation:

To remove an event listener please see the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener)

> Given an event listener previously added by calling
>   addEventListener(), you may eventually come to a point at which you
>   need to remove it. Obviously, you need to specify the same type and
>   listener parameters to removeEventListener() (...)

### Solution:

```
function myTapEvent(evt) {
    addMarker(evt);
}

function setUpClickListener(map) {
  // Attach an event listener to map
  map.addEventListener('tap', myTapEvent);
}

function addMarker(myevt) {
  map.removeEventListener('tap', myTapEvent);
  ///more code...
}
```